# SQL- Last 4 weeks with date column

Tags: sql

USERS

```
   ID  TIMEMODIFIED
    1   1400481271
    2   1400481489
    3   1400486453
    4   1400486525
    5   1401777484
```

I have timemodified field, From timemodified, I need to get the rows of last 4 weeks by taking from today's date.

```
SELECT id FROM USERS
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timemodified,'%d-%m-%Y') >= curdate() 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timemodified,'%d-%m-%Y') < curdate()-1
```

Comment: What rdbms do you use?

Comment: SELECT ID FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID > (nowDateTImeSecound-4weekSecound)

Comment: Date functions are rdbms specific. which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Date functions are specified in ANSI SQL, and a few dbms products are compliant, but too many are not...

Comment: Matteo 'Ingannatore' G - I had edited the query

Comment: But you have still not specified dbms...

Comment: jarlh - Iam using PHP, MYSQLI. I am n't aware of which DBMS it comes under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your times are already in Unix timestamp format. Bear in mind that it'll be far more efficient to compare `[TIMEMODIFIED]` against the *current date* converted to a Unix timestamp. In addition, you don't need to check any upper bound unless `[TIMEMODIFIED]` can be in the future.

Try:

```
-- 60x60x24x7x4 = 2419200 seconds in four weeks
SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200;  

SELECT id FROM USERS
WHERE timemodified >= @unix_four_weeks_ago;
```

*NB.* Four weeks ago (i.e. today – 28 days) was 1,437,696,000 (24th July) at the time of this answer. The latest record in the sample you provided has a timestamp going back to the 3rd June 2014, and so none of these records will be returned by the query.

Comment: Adam Frederick Wiseman - how could we write SET @unix_four_weeks_ago = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200;  In php, it wasn't working but in sql, it was working

Comment: If you need to call this specific statement via PHP, you could try: `SELECT id FROM USERS
WHERE timemodified >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(curdate()) - 2419200);`